# jQuery UI get dragged/dropped offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the ui object's dropped offset value. As in the offset at the dropped position and not the element's initial position.

The following code hasn't worked for me:

```
$(ui.helper).offset().left;
$(ui.helper).draggable().offset().left;
$(ui.helper).droppable().offset().left;
```

Each of those returns the initial offset of the element. How do I get the dropped offset value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not familiar with the plugin, but assuming they're using basic jqueryui drag and drop, try

```
ui.offset
```

which is an object with properties `top` and `left`, relative to the page

Comment: That seems to only return an object. If I use ui.offset.left it returns [object]. Is there something I'm missing in that method? Thanks :)

Comment: @Baez, I suggest you `console.log` it, maybe the plugin adds some extra data/properties, but the basic functionality works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nPHJH/